# How to create a divider in a dialog box

Tags: android

I have a dialog box with two buttons at the bottom. How do I create a divider above these buttons? My XML is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="400dp" 
>   

<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/imageView2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/username" 
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
android:orientation="horizontal"> 

<Button 
android:id="@+id/start" 
android:textSize="18sp" 
android:layout_marginRight="2dip" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
android:padding="5dip" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:text="Start" /> 

<Button 
android:id="@+id/cancel" 
android:textSize="18sp" 
android:layout_marginLeft="2dip" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="Cancel" 
android:textColor="#000000" /> 

</LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a ImageView and provide the following attribute,

```
 <ImageView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dip"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:padding="5dip"/>
```

There is nothing like a Divider attribute that you could set for a Layout. Dividers are available for ListView only.

So you might have to change your linear layout like this,

```
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"> 

 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  >

  <ImageView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dip"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:padding="5dip"/>

</LinearLayout> 


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/start" 
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="2dip" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
    android:padding="5dip" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:text="Start" /> 

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/cancel" 
    android:textSize="18sp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dip" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Cancel" 
    android:textColor="#000000" /> 

        </LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sorry i did not get you what is the use of imageview placeing ther...i need a line above the buttons

Comment: yes. To draw a line above the buttons you need some kind of View right? You can't simply place a line in a layout. YOu either need to have a image which looks likes a line or make the ImageView to look like a line. that's what I have did here. If you could just give it a try and see how it looks you will understand what am trying to do.

Comment: so u want me to put my button on the imageview?

Comment: No. I just want you to change the linear layout containing the two buttons in such a way you could add a ImageView on top of the buttons. So that it will look like the way exactly you wanted. Did you use the code I have provided? I didnt check it though.

Comment: yeah i tried, i have put my buttons on image view it it looks exactly what i want..thankyou

Comment: great my friend. At last it helped you I guess. So how abt doing me a favor by accepting this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Using View

```
<View android:layout_height="2px" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
         />
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came up something based on Nirav's answer

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="254dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/dialogbox_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/selectattachment"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

          <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/blue" />

           <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
             android:orientation="horizontal"> 


           <Button 
             android:id="@+id/start" 
             android:textSize="18sp" 
             android:layout_marginRight="2dip" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" 
             android:padding="5dip" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
             android:text="Start" /> 

           <Button 
             android:id="@+id/cancel" 
             android:textSize="18sp" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="2dip" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:text="Cancel" 
             android:textColor="#000000" /> 

</LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout>
```